# Exclude a command in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following `ENTRYPOINT` in my Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT["/setup.sh"]
```

I need to run a container without running `setup.sh` and run install.sh.
How do I do it?

Comment: [Override the entrypoint (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime).

Comment: If you change `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD`, then you can very easily `docker run your-image /app/another_command --with-options` without special Docker syntax.  An installation script you also may want to `RUN` in the Dockerfile, instead of at container startup time.

Comment: Rename the question: how to override an image's dockerfile entrypoint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your docker entrypoint when executing docker run :

```
docker run -d --rm --entrypoint WHATEVER_COMMAND_YOU_WANT image_name
```

It will replace your dockerfile' entrypoint.

Comment: However it was solved my problem. But if a Docekerfile has more than one `ENTRYPOINT` and user only want to discard one `ENTRYPOINT`, How can user do it? for exampe entpoint1 entpoint2 and entpoint3. And user want to run entpint1 and entpoint2 and discard entpoint3.

Comment: An entrypoint is unique, it cannot be 2 entrypoints in one dockerfile, otherwise one will override the other. But it can be an entrypoint AND a CMD (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile)